# In LightTable, how do you change Clojure version?

Tags: clojure, lighttable

Currently I am using LightTable to run clojure projects, and with Leiningen I can specify a version for a project. However, for .clj files that are not part of a project, it seems the LightTable REPL says the clojure version is 1.5.1.

I would like to set it to 1.7.0 for all .clj files, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is described in [LightTable FAQ](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-set-the-default-clojure-version-when-running-instarepl-outside-of-the-context-of-a-clojure-project):

> ### How do I set the default Clojure version when running Instarepl outside of the context of a Clojure project?
>
> Update `plugins/clojure/runner/resources/project.clj` by adding/changing `:dependencies` `[[org.clojure/clojure "x.x.x" ]]` where `x.x.x` is of course the Clojure version you want to use by default in your Instarepl sessions whenever LightTable doesn't run in the context of a Clojure project (i.e. double clicking on a shortcut on the desktop to run LightTable).

Per http://docs.lighttable.com/#plugins-directory, running the command `App: Light Table version` to get plugin directory.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have given this a try, yet even after adjusting this (from `1.5.1` to `1.7.0`), when running `clojure-version` in a .`clj` file, the result is still `1.5.1`.

Comment: Please, provide the full path of the `project.clj` file you modified. Also did you restart your LightTable instance? I tested it locally and it worked correctly.

Comment: I did restart, but it didn't seem to have any effect. Here is the full path from the file I edited `C:\Desktop\lighttable-0.8.1-windows\resources\app\plugins\Clojure\runner\resources\project.clj`

Comment: I think you need to change the file under different location: http://docs.lighttable.com/#plugins-directory. In your case it will be somewhere under `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\LightTable`.

Comment: Ah did not realise the correct file was in AppData. Modified and it has correctly changed to version `1.7.0`.

Comment: How can I set the global Light Table Clojure version? For me the value in using Light Table is in not having to set up a project each time and seeing quick evaluation results.